# Using Inheritance in Masstransit

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, masstransit, request-response

Let us say that I have the following structure:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Id;
}

public class FirstChild:Parent
{
    public string FirstName;
}

public class SecondChild:Parent
{
    public string LastName;
}
```

And I have two services contacting via Request/Response messaging method.

My First service sends a message and expects either FirstChild or SecondChild as a response, so what I did is:

```
var client = bus.CreateRequestClient<CommandType, Parent>(serviceAddress, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
var response = await client.Request(command);
```

The issue is that response is sent from second service containing Id and FirstName/LastName but received by first service containing only Id.

How can I override this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compose your classes rather than inherit them.

In general favour composition over inheritance [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance?rq=1)

It will, for the most part, result in more flexible and easier to maintain code.

So rather than inherit parent, compose with it like this:

```
public class FirstChild
{
   Parent parent {get; set;}
   string firstName {get; set;}
}
```

In this way you are stating that FirstChild 'has-a' parent rather than FirstChild 'is-a' parent.

I believe this is fundamentally where your problem lies.

[MassTransit documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/understand/message-contracts.html) rightly cautions against using inheritance in messages. Don't confuse your message design with OO design. A message is only state without behavior.